# Diferença de conversão de Array para ArrayList com "asList" e com construtor

Tags: java, array, lista, desempenho, construtor

Qual a diferença entre essas duas formas de conversão de um *array*? Se houver alguma diferença, a mesma impacta no desempenho?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(meuArray);

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(meuArray));
```

Comment: Uma diferença é que `asList` retorna uma lista que não pode ter seu tamanho alterado, então chamar `add`, `remove` e `clear` em `list` lançam exceção (`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`), mas em `arrayList` não. Se vc não vai usar estes métodos, o fator de decisão passa a ser o que o Maniero comenta na resposta dele abaixo. E para saber se impacta no desempenho, só fazendo testes de desempenho para saber :-) (talvez para listas muito grandes e/ou com elementos que ocupam muita memória tenha uma diferença significativa, mas de qq forma, só testando para saber)

Comment: Isso mesmo @hkotsubo, ele não retorna a classe `java.util.ArrayList` e sim a classe  `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O primeiro está atribuindo uma lista para `list`, só que esta lista será baseada no *array* que está sendo usado como base (`meuArray`), então no fundo `list` é só uma referência para a lista.

O segundo faz o mesmo com o argumento do construtor, mas o construtor de `ArayList` tem como função copiar o conteúdo que recebe como lista, então ele pegará a referência recebida e copiara cada elemento para uma nova lista, portanto é muito mais lento, mas terá uma lista isolado.

A questão é se deseja manter a mesma lista ou não. A diferença está no construtor e não no método `asList()`. O primeiro não constrói nada, ele apenas usa o que já foi construído pelo `asList()`, e este método geralmente não constrói nada forte também, ele até constrói um objeto de lista, mas ele referenciará o *array* de forma direta e não fará cópia alguma.

Comment: "o construtor de ArrayList tem como função copiar o conteúdo que recebe como lista" Isso está na especificação ou é um detalhe de implementação?

Comment: @Gabriel Não sei porque não vi a especificação, nem sei se tem, porque isto não faz parte da linguagem e sim da biblioteca, então só a documentação da implementação padrão existe como especificação, e ela é muito ruim dando margem pra interpretação. O fato é que foi feito assim, então todo mundo que queira ser compatível tem que fazer igual, não importa como seja implementado, a semântica deve ser de cópia de dados, pelo menos neste construtor, não há garantias que outro construtor seja diferente, este é assim. Dá para questionar, mas na prática é assim.